# Can you get full (real-time) PPG signal from Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

Does the HealthKit SDK allows you to get the PPG signal from the Apple watch in real-time? I am doing research on heart activity and really need to be able to extract that signal at high-frequency from a wearable device. Is there a way to get it from the Apple Watch?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, the real-time signal is not available.

Comment: What about the full signal at a high sample rate (say 30/60Hz) but received in batches at a delayed rate? And, also if not possible, do you know any other wearables that would offer this?